# Exporting Octopus Deploy project doesn't create json file

Tags: export, octopus-deploy

I'm using Octo.exe 4.0.4 and Octopus version 3.4.12, and I'm trying to export a project from an Octopus Deploy server but I'm not getting an output file.

I can connect to the server, and list the projects, but when I run the export process it seems to stop at the point it should find the project group.

Here's a screenshot of the output.

[image]

I've tried running this from the machine which hosts the Octopus Server, as well as a tentacle, and I get identical results.

I've also tried not putting quotes around the project name and output file, since they aren't actually required here, and again same results.

According to the Octopus docn, the results should be something like this:

```
Octopus Deploy Command Line Tool, version 1.0.0.0

Handshaking with Octopus server: http://localhost/Octopus
Handshake successful. Octopus version: 2.4.4.43; API version: 3.0.0
Finding exporter 'project'
Beginning the export
Finding project: OctoFX Rate Service
Finding project group for project
Finding variable set for project
Finding deployment process for project
Finding NuGet feed for deployment process...
Finding NuGet feed for step Database
Finding NuGet feed for step Rate Service
Export file C:\tmp\OctoFX_Rate_Service.json successfully created.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was a bug in Octo.exe v4.0.4.

It has been fixed in v4.0.7, and I can now export my project.